# How to create rounded shadow?

Tags: css

Many times I created simple shadows but now I need to create rounded shadow. Like on the picture
[image]

Is it possible to do this with CSS??

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: -2px 0px 79px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -2px 0px 79px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -2px 0px 79px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Comment: What did you try? show your effort.

Comment: Looks like you could do it with border-radius and pseudo elements with box-shadows.

Comment: Don't focus on the asset but on the final design. Then go for it! And if you get stuck, come back here with your code! :)

Comment: @ Yazan W Yusuf check my effort

Comment: Use pseudo elements - the box shadow you are trying to achieve doesn't work with the border-radius on the parent element. You can see the shadow is hidden along the left and right edges and fully visible in the middle. So your parent element should be `overflow:hidden` and you should create two pseudo elements (without border-radius), one off the top and one off the bottom and give each of them a box-shadow.

Comment: Proof of concept with pseudo elements: https://jsfiddle.net/2otgt5fu/

Comment: @Adam thank you for the answer. Let me check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your example image is a linear gradient in a round container, so do that:

```css
.round-shadow-clip {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.round-shadow {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), transparent 20%, transparent 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -10%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  width: 120%;
}

html {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAIAAAAC64paAAAALklEQVQ4y2N89+4dA24gKCiIR5aJgQIwqnlkaGb8//8/Hun379+PBtioZko0AwAA0Ajuvut+RAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg');
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="round-shadow-clip">
  <div class="round-shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, there is mo meed in the background image)) it was just example. Your solution as LGSon's work for me perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

With pseudo you can do this

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%/40%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;  
  left:0; right:0; top: -5px; height: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
div::after {
  top: auto; bottom: -5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 -25px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how flexible position absolute is for the `before` and `after` peudo-elements. Can you elaborate on this at all?

Comment: @Martin Flexible how? ... change the width and it works too: https://jsfiddle.net/uucq58us/ ... or what do you mean?

Comment: It is as flexible as for any other child element, which means parent element must have position other than `static`.

Comment: I was wondering will these work with things like floating elements or with inline-blocks or with flexbox elements? does it matter to the absoluteness of the pseudo elements, the display type of their parents?

Comment: @Martin No, the display type won't matter, and here is sample with `inline-block`: https://jsfiddle.net/uucq58us/2/